# Premier Elements "Time Slider" in Premier Pro

Tags: premiere, premiere-elements

I have just upgraded from Premier Elements to Premier Pr CC.

Premier Elements had a slider under the video playback area that allowed you to playback the video at different speeds or backwards. I found this really useful for looking for a certain bit in the video. It allowed you to quickly zoom to roughly the right bit of the video and then find the specific frame.

Does such a thing exist in Premier Pro? I've not been able to find it anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI part you are looking for is called (depending on your locale, and local film industry) the shuttle, or jogger.

I don't know if Premiere supports the exact same graphical control.

**However** using the [J] [K] and [L] keys on your keyboard lets you:

[J] / [L] move backward / forward (moves fast for each press of the same button; moves slower in the same direction when pressing the opposite)

[K] Stops playback

Using these keys, you can shuttle around footage in the same manner as you previously used your mouse the the GUI interface.

Comment: OK, thanks. That sounds useful. I'll give it a try. I'll not mark this as the answer just yet to go others the chance in case this ui element does exist.